# How can I reset the domain-verification process in Google Apps for Business?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, verification

As part of my App Engine application, I decided to configure an already-purchased custom domain name that would point to the app.  To do this, I was directed to use Google's Apps for Business product.

Unfortunately, verification of the custom domain went bad, which was a surprise, because Google contacted my domain registrar directly.  A week passed, and the domain was still listed as undergoing verification.

Is there a way I can restart the process, and hopefully complete it by a different method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this page:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=96917

Click on the first radio button ("I'm receiving the message 'This domain is already in use.'")

Toward the bottom of the page, there will be a URL template:

```
https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/<your domain name>/VerifyAdminAccountPasswordReset
```

Sign into your Google Apps account, then substitute your domain name in the above URL-template where indicated.

When you visit the resulting URL, Google will ask you for an email address.  You will then get an email supplying data values for a new CNAME record you can add at your domain-registrar's website.  If you do that correctly, Google will then consider your custom domain as verified.